# oracle delete statement in java using prepared statement

Tags: java, sql, oracle, prepared-statement, sql-delete

I have the following code:

```
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
        try {
            connection = OracleDatabaseConnector.getConnection();
            preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE ssn = ?");
            preparedStatement.setString(1, musicians.getSsn());

            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

        } finally {
            DbUtil.close(preparedStatement);
            DbUtil.close(connection);
        }
```

I cant figure out why is not working, when I am refreshing the oracle table using the sqlDeveloper the record is still present.

Comment: Did you forget to commit transaction?

Comment: yes. I added connection.commit(); but  the result is the same.

Comment: You sure musicians.getSsn() is returning what you think it is?

Comment: `PreparedStatement.executeUpdate` returns an integer for the number of rows that were affected.  Is that 1 or 0?  What is that value here?  What does `musicians.getSsn()` return?

Comment: row afected 0. The `musicians.getSsn()` returns a string which is primary key in the table

Comment: OK.  So when the `delete` statement runs, no rows match the key that is being passed in.  Either `musicians.getSsn()` isn't returning the value that you expect or the row isn't visible to the session.  Is it possible that you inserted the row in a different session and haven't committed the insert?  Are you sure that your SQL Developer session and your Java application are connecting to the same database and looking at the same table?

Comment: @justin can you post your comment as answer. The problem was that I forgot to commit when I added a new row. The new row appears in the database but it cannot be updated or deleted.